# Transaction management using Atomikos with Spring-integration not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-integration, ibm-mq, atomikos

I'm trying to use Atomikos Global Transaction management for one of my projects which uses spring integration framework to read a message form IBM MQ and store that messages in database. Although the application works in normal scenarios the behavior when some DB exception occurs is not as expected.

The messages read from MQs are gone in case of DB exception. Ideally the MQ messages should be there for further processing.

Spring Config I'm using is as follows:

Spring Integration config:

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="exch" destination="requestQueue"    channel="jmsInChannel" 
transaction-manager="JtaTransactionManager" acknowledge="transacted" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" />               
<bean id="requestQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
<property name="baseQueueName" value="${receiving.queue.name}" />   
<property name="targetClient" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Hibernate config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">                   
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">
com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform
</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>              
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>                        
</props>
</property>
<property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
```

JMS MQ config:

```
<bean id="inBoundQueueConnectionFactory"
class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnectionFactory">
<property name="hostName">
<value>${receiving.queue.hostname}</value>
</property>
<property name="port">
<value>${receiving.queue.port}</value>
</property>
<property name="queueManager">
<value>${receiving.queue.manager}</value>
</property>
<property name="channel">
<value>${receiving.queue.channel}</value>
</property>
<property name="transportType">
<value>1</value>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
<property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
<property name="sessionCacheSize" value="5"/>
<property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"
class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
<property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="inBoundQueueConnectionFactory" />
<property name="username" value="${mqSeriesUserName}" />
<property name="password" value="${mqSeriesPassword}" />
</bean>

<bean id="inBoundConnectionFactory" class="com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean"> 
<property name="xaConnectionFactory" ref="inBoundQueueConnectionFactory"/> 
<property name="uniqueResourceName" value="mq1"/>   
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
<property name="transactionTimeout" value="120"/> 
<property name="forceShutdown">
<value>false</value>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp" >
</bean>

<bean id="JtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
depends-on="atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction">
<property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
<property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
<property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Please let me know if I'm missing out something in the configurations.

Comment: We don't see how you configure `JtaTransactionManager` for the DB operation. Plus it would be great to see some `org.springframework` `DEBUG` logs in case of that problem, when DB fails, but JMS commits any way. On the other side it isn't clear that your downstream flow is single-threaded after `jmsInChannel`. Maybe you're doing message shifting to a new thread via `ExecutorChannel` or `QueueChannel` and so on.

Comment: It also looks like you are passing the wrong connection factory `jmsConnectionFactory` into the channel adapter instead of the Atomikos one.

Comment: I changed the connection factory to `jmsQueueConnectionFactory` & added below as mentioned by Artem

`<property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="JtaTransactionManager"></property>`

But I get below error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.transactionManager(CMTTransaction.java:57)
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.reset(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:128)
 at

Comment: Also tried writing a class `AtomikosJtaPlatform extends AbstractJtaPlatform` and giving that as jta platform in hibernate config. With that change I get `HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction`